# Does blender animated characters follow physics in unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

If i created a animating character that kicks with leg. and imported to unity. Now if i make that character to kick a gameObject will it really make motion in that gameObject.

What i mean is will it follow physics like other game objects. Can this be done by adding a rigidbody and collider components. Please explain me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Blender has nothing to do with the phisix behaviour later in Unity.
If you can import the animation properly you could use this:

http://unity3d.cba.pl/Documentation/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animation-animatePhysics.html

From the documentation: this works only with a kinematic rigidbody.

Hope this helped.